# VS2012 Crashes Loading Resource File with Byte Array

Tags: crash, arrays, visual-studio-2012, unhandled-exception, resource-editor

I used to use VS2010, which had no trouble loading System.Byte[] (byte array) from a resource file, however now when I open the same resource file with Visual Studio 2012 (VS2012) crashes.

Here is a format copied from the Resources.resx file:

```
  <data name="BYTEARRAY_1" type="System.Byte[], mscorlib">
<value>
    e1xydGYxXGFuc2lcYW5zaWNwZzEyNTJcZGVmZjBcZGVmb
    c1xmcHJxMlxmY2hhcnNldDAgQXJpYWw7fXtcZjFcZnJvb
    ...
    NCAqKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKipccGFy
```

My question is what is wrong and how do I fix it?  What is the proper format now?

A second question is how do I add a new byte array to a resource file.  I see the capability to insert images, strings, files, and icon, just not a byte array.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I took was to recode and simply insert a file as a resource.  Files as a resource can load as a byte array.  It was a bit of work, but at least files are easier to maintain.

Microsoft still has a bug, which they introduced in Visual Studio 2012 (VS2012), but their bug actually served me well.